# list all the days for a particular month based on user input mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

1. This is my html form for user to choose month and year:

---

```
<!-- MONTH AND YEAR PICKER -->
<label class="control-label col-md-3">Choose Month and Year</label>
<div class="col-md-4">

    <!--<input class="form-control" type="month" placeholder="Select Month" name="month" id="month" required>-->

    <select class="form-control" data-placeholder="SELECT MONTH" name="month" id="month" required>
        <option value="">Select Month</option>                                          
            <?php
                for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
                    $mth = date("F",mktime(0,0,0,$i,1,date("Y")));
                    echo "<option value='$mth'>$mth</option>";

                }
            ?>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">  

    <!--<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Select Year" id="year" required>-->

    <select class="form-control" data-placeholder="SELECT YEAR" name="year" id="year" required>
        <option value="">Select Year</option>

            <?php
                foreach(range(2013, (int)date("Y")) as $year) {
                    echo "\t<option value='".$year."'>".$year."</option>\n\r";
                }

            ?>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
        <input type="submit" class="btn green" name="btn_search" id="btn_search" onClick="printPreview(document.getElementById('month).value,document.getElementById('year').value)" value="Search"></input>
        <button type="button" class="btn default" onClick="location.href='manhour_report.php'">Clear</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function printPreview(month,year){
        window.open('manhour_reportdata.php?month=' + month + '&year=' + year);
    }
</script>
```

---

2.This is my php and mysql query:

---

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["btn_search"])){
    func_setValid("Y");

    $month = $dates['month'];
    $year = $dates["year"];   



    $query="SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT timesheet_head.project_title) AS project_title, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT customer.State) AS State, 
            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT customer.Name) as Name, timesheet_dtl.date, timesheet_head.*, project.*, 
            SUM(timesheet_dtl.hours) AS hours
            FROM timesheet_head JOIN project JOIN timesheet_dtl JOIN customer
            WHERE timesheet_head.project_no = project.DocRefNo_c
            AND project.ConCustNum = customer.CustNum
            AND timesheet_dtl.timesheet_head_code = timesheet_head.code
            AND timesheet_dtl.date >= DATE_SUB('2013-01-01', INTERVAL 31 DAY) 
            GROUP BY timesheet_dtl.date
            ORDER BY timesheet_dtl.date";

    $result = mysql_query($query); 
    $no = 1;
    $total = 0;
    $totalrow = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if($totalrow > 0){
        echo "<td colspan='4'>Total Record(s): ".$totalrow."</td>";
    }else{
        echo "<tr><td colspan = '4'> No Record(s) Found </td></tr>";
    }

    echo"
            <table class='table-bordered table-hover' width='100%'>
                <th rowspan='4' width='2%' style='text-align:center'>#</th>
                <th rowspan='4' width='7%' style='text-align:center'>Date</th>
                <td></td>
            </table>";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "
            <table class='table-bordered table-hover' width='100%'>
            <tr>
                <td width='2%' style='text-align:center' rowspan='4'>".$no."</td>
                <td width='7%' style='text-align:center' bgcolor='lightgrey' rowspan='4'>".date('d-M-Y', strtotime($row['date']))."</td>
                <td bgcolor='lightgrey'>".$row['State']."</td>
                <tr><td bgcolor='lightgrey'>".$row['project_title']."</td></tr>
                <tr><td>".$row['Name']."</td></tr>
                <tr><td>".$row['hours']."</td></tr>
            </tr>
            </table>";
        $total += $row['hours'];   
        $no++;
    }

    echo "<table class='table-bordered' width='100%'><tr>
            <th style='text-align:center' width='9%'>TOTAL</th>
            <th style='text-align:left'>".number_format($total,2)."</th>
        </tr></table>";

}else if(!isset($_GET["btn_search"])){
    //$timezone = (date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London"));
    $year = date("Y");
    $month = date("M");
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

---

I have a date type column in my table. When a user selects a particular month, it should list all the days for the month as a result. When user click search event, there is a null value. But for the above result, when the user selected the month and year, it lists all available dates from the table without following the user input. What i need to know is: "how can i list all days for a month that user have selected which is fetch from my db"? Could someone guide me to solve this? Also, when user click search, the result will have to pop out on new window. I tried to do it but nothing happened when i click search.

*Sorry for my bad english

Comment: **Warning** : You are using `mysql_xx` functions which are deprecated since many years and removed in newer php versions for security reasons. Have a look at `mysqli_xx` or `PDO` for a better replacement